# javascript update a setInterval with input value

Tags: javascript

hey i was just wondering if someone could help me work out way my script is not working i'm trying to get it to update the speed for the setInterval using a input number box but it does not seen to update the value each time the value is change in the input and i really don't get why this is happening any ideas why?

```js
var nametags = null;
var nametag = document.getElementById('names');
var speed = document.querySelector('input[id="speeds"]');

var partyTags = function() {
  clearInterval(nametags);
  if (nametags !== null) {
    nametags = null;
  } else {
    var delay = speed.value;
    nametags = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('hud-party-tag')[0].value = '&#' +
        Math.random().toString(9).substring(9, 5) + ' ' + [nametag.value] + ' ' + '&#' +
        Math.random().toString(9).substring(9, 5);
    }, delay);
  }
}

speed.addEventListener("input", partyTags);

partyTags();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="speeds" value="1000">
<input type="text" maxlength="35" id="names" value="NAME HERE">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="hud-party-tag" disabled>
```

Comment: Seems to be working.. what is the expected output? http://jsfiddle.net/naho6gcL/

Comment: convert speed variable into integer: var speed = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[id="speeds"]'));

Comment: change var nametags = null;   to var nametags;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the check of **nametag** for **NULL** value, in particular when the input event was detected, the first time you call **partyTags()** it enters into the **IF** condition and set **nametag** to **NULL**, after this the method finished and the interval isn't updated. The next call to **partyTags()** enters the **ELSE** section and update the interval, and so on...  So, try next code and see if it works now:

```js
var nametags = null;
var nametag = document.getElementById('names');
var speed = document.querySelector('input[id="speeds"]');

var partyTags = function()
{
    clearInterval(nametags);
    var delay = speed.value;

    nametags = setInterval(
        function()
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName('hud-party-tag')[0].value = '&#' +
            Math.random().toString(9).substring(9, 5) + ' ' + [nametag.value] + ' ' + '&#' +
            Math.random().toString(9).substring(9, 5);
        },
        delay
    );
}

speed.addEventListener("input", partyTags);

partyTags();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="speeds" value="1000">
<input type="text" maxlength="35" id="names" value="NAME HERE">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="hud-party-tag" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this call in the code

partyTags();

you called partyTags method twice